# Preview Contact form 7 entry before it's submitted

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 for building a multistep application form and before submitting the form I need to add a preview/summary of all fields filled before.
I couldn't find a plugin that can do this so I thought to add a JavaScript function that saves the value of a form field to a variable and displays it on a div and repeat the procedure for all the fields that I have used.

I have two questions :

- Is this the right way to handle that problem or can you suggest something else?
- I have used the following code to take the value of a cf7 text field with id #companyname and put that value to a div with id  #div1 but is not working.

How can I take the value of a form field and display it on another div on the save form?

```
jQuery( '#companyname' ).on( 'blur' , function(){
    var company_name = JQuery('#companyname').val();
    jQuery('#div1').text = company_name;
});
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `text()` method was used improperly (it takes an argument, not assignment). You can also use `jQuery(this)` to reference the current object. You also had a typo with "JQuery", notice the capitalization.

```
jQuery('#companyname').on('blur', function() {
    var company_name = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery('#div1').text(company_name);
});
```